# EF 7 (Core) : dependent object in another database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF 7, using 1.0.0-rc1-final
using database first design (database already exists so have to use it)

I have 2 entities - The parent entity is in one database, the dependent child entity is in another database on the same server instance

I have 2 database Contexts respectively one for each database and registered the entities accordingly, however when Eager loading the parent entity (using include), it still tries to locate the dependent entity in the same database

am I doing something wrong ?

In the following code all other objects which were not relevant to the problem have been removed

parent:

```
[Table("tblEventsDates")]
public class Session
{
    [Column("EventDateID")]
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    [Column("EventDateName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }               
    [Column("EventDate")]
    public DateTime SessionDate { get; set; }        
    [Column("EventDateTime")]
    public DateTime SessionTime { get; set; }
    [Column("EventDateMinutes")]
    public decimal? SessionDurationInMinutes { get; set; }
    [Column("EventDateArrival")]
    public DateTime? ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    [Column("EventCapacity")]
    public int SessionCapacity { get; set; }

    //navigation properties        
    [JsonIgnore]        
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]        
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public HardTicketRange HardTicketRange {get;set;}

}
```

Dependent Entity:

```
    [Table("tblhardTicketRanges")]
    public class HardTicketRange {
        public int HardTicketRangeId { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        [Column("Finish")]
        public int End { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //navigation properties`enter code here`
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public Session Session { get; set; }

    }
```

Second DbContext:

```
public class TicketingDataDbContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<HardTicketRange>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Session)
            .WithOne(e => e.HardTicketRange);            

        modelBuilder.Entity<HardTicketRange>(entity => {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.HardTicketRangeId);
        });          

    }

    public virtual DbSet<HardTicketRange> HardTicketRanges { get; set; }
}
```

First DBContext

```
 public partial class TicketingCentralDbContext : DbContext {

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Session>()
            .HasOne(e => e.HardTicketRange)
            .WithOne(b => b.Session);            

        modelBuilder.Entity<Session>(entity => {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.SessionId);                              
        });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Query to select parent entity

```
var sessions = from s in _cxt.Sessions.Include(e=>e.HardTicketRange)
                       where s.EventId == eventId                                                      
                       orderby s.SessionDate, s.SessionTime  descending
                       select s;
```

SQL generated by EF 7 - which is incorrect as the 2 tables exist in different database

```
SELECT [e].[EventDateID], [e].[EventDateArrival], [e].[EventId], [e].

[EventDateName], [e].[EventCapacity], [e].[EventDate], [e].[EventDateMinutes], [e].[EventDateTime], [t].[HardTicketRangeId], [t].[Description], [t].[Finish], [t].[SessionId], [t].[Start]
FROM [tblEventsDates] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN [tblhardTicketRanges] AS [t] ON [t].[SessionId] = [e].[EventDateID]
WHERE [e].[EventId] = @__eventId_0
ORDER BY [e].[EventDate], [e].[EventDateTime] DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure Entity Framework of any version supports cross database relationships.  You would need to use the two context separately and merge the results yourself.

Comment: yea, I guess you are right, If I do need something like this I'd probably have to create a view and a data model based on the view which queries the two sources